Non blocking getchar microcontroller
I know this has been asked millions of times in millions of websites, but everything I find is just not working for me. I am coding a Raspberry Pi Pico in C, and want to do something as simple as
if (one_or_more_bytes_available_in_stdin())
    char c = getchar();
else
    continue_with_life();

There is the getchar_timeout_us which fails strangely for me, I think it has to do with the fact that it probably uses some sleep inside, and I am calling this inside an interrupt, which can be problematic according to here.
How can the one_or_more_bytes_available_in_stdin function be implemented?

Assuming Linux, you can check if something can be read from STDIN_FILENO (the standard in file-descriptor). This can be done through epoll, poll or select; Or making STDIN_FILENO non-blocking and using read to check for the EWOULDBLOCK error.

it's a microcontroller interrupt routine, not linux

How does getchar_timeout_us fail for you? What is standard input connected to? A serial port? Then you should be able to set up an interrupt every time something is received by the serial controller, and that interrupt function could update a circular buffer that holds the input. Then instead of reading from standard input, read from this buffer.

@Someprogrammerdude actually I was using the hardware UART and uart_is_readable was my one_or_more_bytes_available_in_stdin. Now I want to move to the USB serial communication. Though it works for some stuff, I am facing very strange behavior in some cases and suspect about this. But I don't see how to avoid the timed getchar function.

It might be better to ask about the problem you have getting your attempt to work with the USB serial connection. It's more likely that someone will be able to help you with that specific problem, than the rather generic and broad question you now have. Please take some time to refresh [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist.

Please explain in your question why you need to run the functions directly from an interrupt handler. Wouldn't it be possible to set a flag in the interrupt handler and read the input in a main loop or a periodically called function if the flag is set? This way you might be able to use getchar_timeout_us.

Obviously you should not be calling any stdio.h bloat lib functions from inside an interrupt. The function isn't the problem, your code is. As for better alternatives to stdio.h, hacking together your own minimal UART driver + API is trivial on most microcontrollers.

What I want to do is to modify this example such that, instead of using the hardware UART 1 or 2, it works with the USB connection. Replacing uart_getc←getchar, uart_putc←putchar, and uart_is_readable←one_or_more_bytes_available_in_stdin does the trick. I am not an expert, but it does not sound crazy to me that such function could exist, given that the other one exists.

Please add new information and clarification to your question by [edit]ing it. this is not a forum, comments are not for this. You might want to add a [mre] showing your issue.

You are adding information critical to your question in comments.  SO s not a discussion forum, you need to update your question.  That this is USB is probably critical.

You indicated you are doing this inside of an interrupt (ISR).  If that is the case then the assumption is that you are in the ISR for a reason. You need to confirm the reason is related to your specific stream (data was received or fifo has some data), then you need to figure out how much data is available. (in the pico sdk there is a function that lest you know how many byte are available), then you do a read for only those bytes. Since this is a ISR you copy those bytes into your buffer or queue or whatever you setup to get data out of the ISR.  The timeout_us would typically never be used inside an ISR.
Now if you are using the pico's stk to map stdin from usb or serial then in the background, not ISR, you should be able to setup regular non-blocking file IO from STDIN.  Don't do it myself but I am sure it involves FCTRL or some such.
This looks like it might be helpful:
C non-blocking keyboard input

It may be that reading from the stdin stream will not work in an ISR in all or any circumstances, and it is in any event Ill-advised.  stdin redirected from a file for example would be particularly problematic.
Ideally you would have low level access to the device input buffer (and it clearly must be buffered, to avoid unexpected and undesirable  work in the ISR), but failing that, you can use stdin by using an RTOS thread dedicated to waiting (blocking) on stdin, and placing characters in a FIFO queue that can be read non-blocking in an ISR (or blocking/non-blocking) in any other RTOS thread.
So (pseudocode - not C, illustrative only):
// 128 character FIFO (for example)
static CharacterQueue input( 128 ) ;

void InputTask()
{
    // Wait fire input, place in FIFO
    for(;;)
    {
        int ch = getchar() ;
        if( ch !== EOF ) input.put() ;
    }
}

// Gec character is available,
// return immediately otherwise.
int GetInputNoWait)
{
    int ret = -1 ;
    if( input.count() > 0 )
    {
        ret = input.get() ;
    }
}

// Wait indefinitely
int GetInputWait()
{
    return input.get() ;
}

Of course if you are using an RTOS, it will have a suitable message or chatacter queue mechanism with timeout, blocking and non-blocking semantics, so you could use that directly (rather than explicitly checking the FIFO count).

getchar() is normally a macro (backed up by a function with the same name) that often calls getchar() -> fgetc(stdin) -> read() (in posix systems), and that is part of the C standard library.  As stdio package is defined in C as a buffered system (which can be or not in your implementation), it is very difficult to guess what can be happening there without having a look to the getchar() implementation you are using (and which you don't provide) Calling a non reentrant function from a multithreaded environment (as an ISR is) is a bet to disaster, so IMHO your question has probably some better answer than this one, but further data must be provided to identify the possible source of your problem.
Calling standard functions from an interrupt handler is normally a bad habit, for this and other reasons.  The buffering structure of the habitual implementations of getchar() just marks the routine as nonreentrant (so they cannot be called from an interrupt handler) Have you read the documentation on that routine in the library documentation of your processor?
